# Remove Items From XML Based Off Date

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

I am trying to set up a php script that will look through an XML, and if an item has a pubDate of more than 7 days old, it deletes the entire item.  What I have come up with so far is:

```
<?php

$rss = new DOMDocument();
$url = 'http://www.url.net/app/Test.xml';
$rss->load($url);
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('date')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);

}

$limit = 50;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$newDate = date("D, d M Y G:i:s -0400", strtotime("-8 day"));
    $date = date('D, d M Y G:i:s -0400', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        $theitem = date('D, d M Y G:i:s -0400', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
 if ($date > $newDate) {
        echo "Don't delete";
    }

    else {
        echo "Delete";
    }


}


?>
```

This gives me 50 echoes, only 1 of which is Delete, while the XML actually only houses 10 items, and only one of them should remain.  Can you give me some guidance for getting this set up right, and then also on how to remove the item, once I have identified them properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing the values as strings in the RSS date format. This is something like `Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000` and for example `Fri` will be smaller then `Mon`. I suggest you compare the result of `strtotime()` directly.

```
$newDate = strtotime("-8 day");
$date = strtotime($feed[$x]['date']);
if ($date > $newDate) {
     echo "Don't delete";
} else {
  echo "Delete";
}
```

Another way is using Xpath with a callback into PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23683347/2265374

Comment: I tried what you posted, and the return I got was `Don't deleteDon't deleteDon't deleteDon't deleteDon't deleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDeleteDelete`
At this point, there are only 8 entries, so it should have in no way been that many echoes.

Seems my limit in the loop may be messing things up, as it is forcing it to always return 50 echoes.

Comment: I changed my for loop to `for ($i = 0; $i < count($feed); $i++)` and this properly returned everything based off of what your answer was.